# graph_draw missing from graph_tool osx?

Tags: python, macos, graph-tool

I am trying to use the method graph_draw in graph_tool. I see references to it in the site_packages and in documentation

```
./cgenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/graph_tool/draw/__init__.py:   graph_draw
./cgenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/graph_tool/draw/__init__.py:__all__ = ["graph_draw", "graphviz_draw", "fruchterman_reingold_layout",
./cgenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/graph_tool/draw/__init__.py:    >>> gt.graph_draw(g, pos=pos, output="graph-draw-fr.pdf")
./cgenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/graph_tool/draw/__init__.py:       gt.graph_draw(g, pos=pos, output="graph-draw-fr.png")
./cgenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/graph_tool/draw/__init__.py:    >>> gt.graph_draw(g, pos=pos, output="graph-draw-arf.pdf")
./cgenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/graph_tool/draw/__init__.py:       gt.graph_draw(g, pos=pos, output="graph-draw-arf.png")
./cgenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/graph_tool/draw/__init__.py:            graph_draw(u, mivs, vertex_fillcolor=mivs)
./cgenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/graph_tool/draw/__init__.py:    >>> gt.graph_draw(g, pos=pos, output="graph-draw-sfdp.pdf")
./cgenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/graph_tool/draw/__init__.py:       gt.graph_draw(g, pos=pos, output="graph-draw-sfdp.png")
./cgenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/graph_tool/draw/__init__.py:       http://www.mathematica-journal.com/issue/v10i1/graph_draw.html
./cgenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/graph_tool/draw/__init__.py:            #graph_draw(u, pos)
```

But when I try to access this, it does not exist...

```
>>> x=graph_tool.draw.GraphView
>>> x=graph_tool.draw.graph_draw()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevd_exec.py", line 3, in Exec
    exec exp in global_vars, local_vars
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'graph_draw'
```

Am I missing something?  how should i be accessing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Be sure you have all optional dependencies installed: pycairo, matplotlib, and gtk3 (as well as librsvg, if you are using macports).

Comment: +1, a recent related post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32789062/activating-cairo-dependent-features-of-graph-tool

Comment: On Ubuntu 20.04 LTS `sudo apt install pyton-cairo python3-cairo python-cairo-dev python3-cairo-dev libgtk-3-dev` solved the issue (I already had install matplotlib).

Comment: With homebrew `brew install pygobject3`, `pip install pycairo`.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be an import issue... 
"graph_draw" function is imported from "graph_tool.all" and not from "graph_tool"

I am actually working on OSX 10.10.4 and when I import the "graph_tool" module like this:

```
from graph_tool.all import *  

#create your graph object
g = Graph()

#add vertex 
vertex_1 = g.add_vertex() #here you create a vertex
vertex_2 = g.add_vertex() #here you create a vertex

#add edge
g.add_edge(vertex_1,vertex_2) #add an edge 

#draw you graph 
graph_draw(
    g,
    output="test.png"
)
```

It's works !

If I follow the "import example" you provide you may try also:

```
from graph_tool.all import graph_draw,Graph  

#create your graph object
g = Graph()

#add a vertex at least
g.add_vertex()

#draw you graph 
graph_draw(
    g,
    output_size=(200,200),
    output="test.png"
)
```

Please try to run one of this previous code on your computer to doublecheck if it is a module's import issue or a dependencies/installation issue

Best regards