# Activating cairo-dependent features of graph_tool

Tags: python, cairo, pycairo, graph-tool

I have been using the [graph-tool library](https://graph-tool.skewed.de/) for a while now, thus far I hadn't really been using most of its drawing features. Today when trying to use [graph_tool.draw.graph_draw](https://graph-tool.skewed.de/static/doc/draw.html#graph_tool.draw.graph_draw) I realised that I had configured graph-tool initially without [cairo](http://www.cairographics.org/documentation/pycairo/3/index.html#module-cairo),

```
./configure --disable-cairo
```

and this is exactly the graphics library that graph_draw uses. If I install cairo now, is there a way to activate the features of graph_tool that rely on cairo without having to remove and reinstall the whole graph_tool module? This would spare a few hours of re-installation. (the make process takes about 3 hours on my machine).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to recompile the library, since the cairo-based drawing is implemented in C++.

Comment: Alright, thanks, I'll redo the whole thing again asap. For python2.7, is py2cairo-1.10.0 [found here](http://cairographics.org/pycairo/), the one to install?

Comment: Related question to this: Does the Py3 Debian stretch package come without cairo/graph visualization tools? `'graph_draw' in dir(graph_tool.all)` returns `False` for `graph_tool.__version__ '2.26 (commit b89e6b4e, Thu Nov 9 14:55:43 2017 +0000)'`.

Comment: Yes it does. Maybe you are missing some run-time dependency.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like it's cairo: `RuntimeWarning: Error importing cairo. Graph drawing will not work.` Would it be correct to say that, for the Debian package installation, the graph drawing libraries (GTK+ 3, cairomm, pycairo and matplotlib) need to be installed in addition to python3-graph-tool?